# Core Data NSPredicate casting key value

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I have a data model which has values of type id that I was planning on casting appropriately when needed.

Is it possible for me to cast these as strings and compare them to strings from a UISearchBar using NSPredicate or do I have to use another method?

Maybe something like this:

```
NSPredicate * predicate;
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CAST(%K) contains[cd] %@", employeeID , theSearchBar.text];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The `CAST()` function doesn't work that way.  I think you just have to assume that the `id` returned from `-employeeID` is comparable to a string.